# Compactness of binary sequences metric space

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define a metric space $(X, d)$ as follows. The points in $X$ are all infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s. Given two distinct sequences $\{p_n\}$ and $\{q_n\}$ in $X$,

$d(\{p_n\}, \{q_n\}) = 1/(\textrm{least $n$ such that $p_n$ is not equal to $q_n$})$.

Prove this metric space is compact.

I don't need Tychonoff Theorem or some advanced theorem. I'm in an introduction real analysis class, I clearly cannot cite some obscure theorem.
I planned to use Heine-Borel, because it is bounded by $[0,1]$ but I don't know how to conclude it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

*Every* metric space is closed in itself, so closed and bounded isn't enough. For example, the open interval $(0,1)$ under the usual metric is not compact, but is bounded, and closed in itself.

A better choice is probably to show that every sequence of elements of $X$ has a subsequence that converges to an element of $X.$ And, yes, such a beast will be a sequence of sequences.